# PowerShell Update Registry Value Based on Capital Letter Criteria

Tags: powershell, registry, updates

Thanks to @mklement0 I have the ability to recurse through a registry key to find the value of a registry string value where the letters https contain capital letters before the : symbol.

Taking it another step I would now like the ability or option to change the letters https to all lowercase if found to contain any variation of capital letters.

I believe I need to somehow use Set-Itemproperty to accomplish this.  The pain point for me is, it required the -path parameter.  This is where I'm getting stumped.

Here is the code that mklement0 gave me to find the value if it contains any capital letters

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\Software\MySoftwareKey' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
  Get-ItemProperty Web -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Web |
      Where-Object { ($_ -split ':')[0] -cmatch '\p{Lu}' }
```

I would like to have any https that contain capital letters changed to all lowercase so that the Web registry string value only would always begin with https before the `:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this scenario it is ultimately easier to work directly with [`Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey), the .NET type that `Get-ChildItem` returns for registry paths:

**Note**: Since you're targeting `HKLM:`, i.e. the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` registry hive, you must **run the following code with *elevation* (as an administrator).**

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\Software\MySoftwareKey' -Recurse -ea SilentlyContinue |
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($url = $_.GetValue('Web')) {
      $protocol, $rest = $url -split ':', 2
      if ($protocol -cmatch '\p{Lu}') {
        $_ | Set-ItemProperty -Name 'Web' -Value ($protocol.ToLower() + ':' + $rest)
      }
    }
  }
```

- `if ($url = $_.GetValue('Web'))` checks for a (nonempty) `Web` value and assigns it to `$url`
- `$protocol, $rest = $url -split ':', 2` splits the URL into the part before the `:` (the protocol name, such as `https`) and the rest (`2` is the maximum number of tokens to create).
- As in the command in your question, `$protocol -cmatch '\p{Lu}'` looks case-sensitively (`-cmatch`) for any uppercase letter (`\pL{u}`).
- `$_ | Set-ItemProperty -Name Web -Value ($protocol.ToLower() + ':' + $rest)` rewrites the value with the protocol name converted to all-lowercase.

  - Note: It is tempting to try `$_.SetValue('Web', $protocol.ToLower() + ':' + $rest)` instead, but the `Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey` instances returned by `Get-ChildItem` reflected in `$_` are *read-only*, so that trying to call `.SetValue()` invariably fails, even if your user account has sufficient privileges in principle.